# How to sort an Array that is read from a .txt file in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sorting

Here is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class runsCreated {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String   firstName       = "";
        String   lastName        = "";
        int      hits            = 0;
        int      walks           = 0;
        int      caughtStealing  = 0;
        int      stolenBases     = 0;
        int      atBats          = 0;
        int      totalBases      = 0;
        double   runsCreated     = 0.0;
        double[] runsCreatedList = new double[40];
        double[] sortedList      = new double[40];
        String[] nameList        = new String[40];      
        Scanner  console         = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Asks user for input file name
        System.out.println("Input File Name:");
        String inputFileName = "//Users//Mitchell//Desktop//baseballinput.txt"; //console.next();


        //inputFile will take input from stored input file
        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);

        //in will take input from user defined source 
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFile);

        int i = 0; //counter

        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            lastName           = inFile.next();
            firstName          = inFile.next();
            hits               = inFile.nextInt();
            walks              = inFile.nextInt();
            totalBases         = inFile.nextInt();
            stolenBases        = inFile.nextInt();
            caughtStealing     = inFile.nextInt();
            atBats             = inFile.nextInt();

            runsCreated        = ((hits + walks - caughtStealing) * (totalBases + (.55 * stolenBases)) / (atBats + walks));
            runsCreatedList[i] = runsCreated;       
            sortedList[i] = runsCreatedList[i];

            System.out.print(nameList[i] + ":" + " " + /*will be sortedList[i]*/runsCreatedList[i]);

            i++;
        }

        sortedList[i] = Arrays.sort(sortedList);        
        inFile.close();     
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the `sortedList[i] = Arrays.sort(sortedList);` that it cannot convert from `void` to `double`.  I know it is suppose to be a `double` I just can't figure out how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `Arrays.sort(..)` do? Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort(array);` just sorts the array. It doesn't return anything. [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28double%5B%5D%29). What are you trying to do, if you're expecting a double? Could you give an example?

Comment: the txt file has doubles for runs, hits, walks, totalbases, etc.  i take those from the txt file and put them in an equation and have a new variable called runsCreated.  it does that 40 times so there are 40 different runsCreated.  I am trying to then sort the runs created so that i can print out the Names of each player with the runsCreated from first to last. ex. ( Mguel Cabrera: 150, Andrew McCutchen 149, etc.)  except each player is on there own line.

Comment: I see. Could you also provide an example input file, please? Just two or three lines so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Cabrera Miguel 193 90 353 3 0 555
   Cuddyer Michael 162 46 259 10 3 489
   Mauer Joe 144 61 212 0 1 445
   Trout Mike 190 110 328 33 7 589
   Johnson Chris 165 29 235 0 0 514
   Freeman Freddie 176 66 276 1 0 551 "the start of Each Name starts a new line in the input file"